# Changing title of documents being uploaded - Event Receiver

Tags: c#, events, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, event-handling

Ok so I have a request from a user and I want to achieve it using and Event Receiver.

Basically what she wants is to have a Document Library where users can upload documents. Each document will have a file name like this "UserA - Customization.docx". Now you can imagine that a user can upload many documents that will have an identical name so what we want to do is number the files automatically. So if if UserA uploads the first document, SharePoint will add a number after the name so the file will be called "UserA - Customization - 1.docx" and then he uploads a second document and it will be called "UserA - Customization - 2.docx".

However, now if UserB wants to upload his first document it must be numbered "UserB - Customization - 1.docx" so basically the counter needs to restart if its a new documet and continue from the highest number if the document name already exists.

So basically SharePoint needs to check if the name of the current document exists in the list and if it does add a number next to it, but the number must be 1 greater than the highest document so it will just increase.

Is there any way to do this? Any ideas?

This is what I have come up with so far for simply changing the name of the file adding "-xx" to the filename but this is not working.

```
public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties) 
{ 
    SPFile spf = properties.ListItem.File; 
    string url = properties.AfterUrl; 

    int positionOfSlash = url.LastIndexOf("/"); 
    string pathBeforeFileName = url.Substring(0, positionOfSlash); 
    string newFileName = createNewFileName(url.Substring(positionOfSlash)); 

    string myNewUrl = pathBeforeFileName + newFileName; 

    DisableEventFiring(); 
    spf.MoveTo(myNewUrl); 

    spf.Update(); 
    EnableEventFiring(); 
} 
static string createNewFileName(string oldFileName) 
{ 
    int positionOfPeriod = oldFileName.LastIndexOf("."); 

    string fileName = oldFileName.Substring(0, positionOfPeriod); 
    string fileExtension = oldFileName.Substring(positionOfPeriod); 

    string newFileName = fileName + "-xx" + fileExtension; 

    return newFileName; 
}
```

Where am I going wrong with this code? Thanks for any help!

EDIT: *this is the code I am using in the console app in Visual Studio to attach the EventReceiver to the Document Library.*

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://servername:port/subsite1/subsite2/"))
        {

            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList list = web.Lists["My Doc Library"];

                SPEventReceiverDefinition def = list.EventReceivers.Add();
                def.Assembly = "DocumentLibrary_ClassLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=611205b34d18f14d";
                def.Class = "DocumentLibrary_ClassLib.EventReceiver";
                def.Type = SPEventReceiverType.ItemAdded;
                def.Update();
            }
        }
```

EDIT #2: 
Ok how about something like this?

```
//this will get just the name of the file without the extension and I will send that to the 
//query builder which will count how many files there are with that name and return
int positionOfPeriod = oldFileName.LastIndexOf(".");
string tempFileName = oldFileName.Substring(0, positionOfPeriod);

SPQuery query = BuildArbitraryQuery(properties.List, "Name", tempFileName, true);
```

But now I don't really understand the query in the BuildArbitraryQuery, how can I change this to give me the desired behavior? (sorry if its a total noob question but I've never dealt with C# and EventReceivers before)
  - Well after looking at BuildArbitraryQuery for a while I think I made some sense of it, basically I don't need to change anything? Since it receives the name of the file and the name of the column as a parameter it should be fine right?

Also since items within the list will be something like ClientA Request - 3.docx and I am sending the filename to the BuildArbitraryQuery will be able to find part matches rather than the full match. So for example if the filename BuildArbitraryQuery receives is ClientA Request.docx will it be able to find all other requests from that ClientA? So would ClientA Request - 1.docx, ClientA Request - 2.docx all be included in the calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, tested it and it works.

```
/// <summary>
   /// An item was added.
   /// </summary>
   public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {
       base.ItemAdded(properties);
       SPListItem item = properties.ListItem;

       if (item["Name"] == null)
           return; //or better yet, log

       string oldFileName = item["Name"].ToString();

       SPQuery query = BuildArbitraryQuery(properties.List, "Created By", properties.UserDisplayName, true);

       int count = properties.List.GetItems(query).Count;

       int positionOfPeriod = oldFileName.LastIndexOf(".");
       if (positionOfPeriod == -1)
       {
            fileName = oldFileName;
            fileExtension = "";
        }
       else
       {
             fileName = oldFileName.Substring(0, positionOfPeriod);
             fileExtension = oldFileName.Substring(positionOfPeriod);
        }

       string newFileName = fileName + "-xx" + count.ToString() + fileExtension;

       item["Name"] = newFileName;

       try
       {
           properties.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
           EventFiringEnabled = false;

           item.Update();
       }
       finally
       {
           properties.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
           EventFiringEnabled = true;
       }
   }

   /// <summary>
   /// Builds an arbitrary SPQuery which filters by a single column value.
   /// </summary>
   /// <param name="list">The list you will run the query against.</param>
   /// <param name="columnDisplayName">The Display Name of the column you want to filter.</param>
   /// <param name="value">The value to filter against.</param>
   /// <returns>A new SPQuery object ready to run against the list.</returns>
   public static SPQuery BuildArbitraryQuery(SPList list, string columnDisplayName, string value, bool deepSearch)
   {
       if (list == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("You cannot pass a null list to Helper.BuildArbitraryQuery.");

       if (!list.Fields.ContainsField(columnDisplayName))
           throw new ArgumentException("The SharePoint List \"" + list.Title + "\" does not contain the Field \"" + columnDisplayName + "\".");

       string internalName = list.Fields[columnDisplayName].InternalName;
       SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
       query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"" + internalName + "\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">" + value + "</Value></Eq></Where>";

       if (deepSearch)
           query.ViewAttributes += "Scope='RecursiveAll'";

       return query;
   }
```

Comment: Thank You! But I can't seem to get it working on my Document Library. How does this work, I tried creating a new document with the same name and it just overwrites the old one. And I also tried uploading a document with the same name as on in the list already but that just overwrites it as well...and the file name doesn't change. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I've added the code that I am using in the console project to add this event receiver to the Document Library, to the original post.

Comment: When you upload a document with the same name as what is already in the list, SharePoint doesn't count that as adding a new item.  Instead, sharepoint counts that as an update to the item that originally had that name.

The code I just gave you should run on each *new* item as it is added to the library, and add the numbers to the filename.  Instead of trying to determine how many instances of that document were uploaded by the user by looking in the filename, it just checks the column in SharePoint that records which user uploaded the file.

Does this info help?

Comment: Ok, I tried it with creating a new document using the option 'New Document' on the ribbon. I added some text to the document and clicked 'Save' then it asked for a name so I entered the same name as the document already in the list but then it gave the options to Merge, Overwrite or Rename the document. What do I need to do here for the Event Receiver to work?

Comment: I'm not sure which version of SharePoint you are using, but I don't believe that should matter.  I think, _think_ that the event receiver should run after you make your choice (not sure).

An easier way to test this would be to move the code I gave you into a console application.  You can run console applications on the sharepoint server, if you wrap the code in using(SPSite ...){using(SPWeb...)} statements

At least then you could run it a few times and get a feel for it.  Do you not understand any particular line of code?  I could walk you through it.

Comment: That does help but I have another question. So basically this code would check if the user uploaded a document to the library before and if he did, it will change the filename? I think thats a bit different from my requirement. Lets say I have a file called Request.docx and it can be filled by everyone using SharePoint. When UserA fills in a request the file should be renamed UserA Request - 1.docx so then if the same user adds another file it will be UserA Request - 2.docx...if UserB adds a file it should be named UserB Request - 1.docx and so on... Can I accomplish this?

Comment: In the example you just explained, when UserA uploads Request.docx, that is the first file he has added to the library.  Therefore, the code should rename it to Request-xx1.docx.  When he uploads a different file (not the same file), the code will check how many he has already uploaded, and will rename it to Request-xx2.docx (because this is his second document).  When userB makes a request, he has not uploaded any before, and therefore his file will be changed to Request-xx1.docx.

This appears to me to be the same thing that you just described.  Am I missing anything?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I need to have happen. As per your other comment I am using SharePoint 2010 and Office Word 2010 for editing my documents. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: That should be what the code does!  If you need help figuring it out, let me know, I'll check back here a few more times today.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! But there is a slight change and I just realized this...So this should not be user dependent, basically the User will be written in the file name.  Let me give an example: So this is an internal list to our company, now lets say the BA receives a request for a customization to the product from ClientA (my mistake I called it UserA before). The BA will create a document with the title ClientA Request - 1.docx, now when the same client makes another request, the second request will be named

Comment: ClientA Request - 2.docx. Now say ClientB makes a request, the first document will be Client B Request - 2.docx. The Event Receiver just needs to add the - # after the file name and keep incrementing. So basically the userID of the user that is submitting the document doesn't really matter. Can I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Sure, just replace the section where I use the query with however you would like to come up with the new number

Comment: Ok I've made an edit to the original post (EDIT #2) to show you what I'm thinking for this but I don't really understand the BuildArbitraryQuery so can you help define that a bit? How can I change it to count the number of occurances of the same title? Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Robert, any ideas how I can debug the code? I feel its right the way it is but it still does not rename the file. How should I be testing this? I tried adding a new document but that has not worked.

Comment: BuildArbitraryQuery simply creates a camlquery so you can retrieve only selected items out of the list.  

If you place this in visual studio, and run debug, you should be able to step through the code line by line.

To count the number of items with the same title, I would remove the arbitrary query completely, and simply iterate through the items in the list, comparing the title strings of each item.

Comment: Hi Robert, I've been busy with other requirements but now I have some more time for this. I've since moved the code to ItemAdding event but I have no idea how to debug!!! I am a total beginner to VS. I have attached my EventReceiver to the w3wp process and added a break point at the start of ItemAdding, then I hit Debug but it does not work, the breakpoints turn yellow and I get this message when hovering over them "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document." Any idea what I am doing wrong, how does debugging work for Event Receivers?